# how to count number of files with a specific entry?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

In my script i am using the following...

```
edi824Files=`find $EDI_824_FILE_DIR -name "*$ediFileDate*.edi" -a "(" -mtime -1 ")"`
```

here $ediFileDate should be the current date, and $EDI_824_FILE_DIR has the value like DIR/. e.g: DIR/2014-01-24

the above one is working fine, but it just pull all the files with .edi extensions. But i would like to get only the files with a specific entry. for e.g: the files which containing the value "*824*". how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
find $EDI_824_FILE_DIR -name "*$ediFileDate*.edi" -a "(" -mtime -1 ")" -exec grep -l "824" {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Pipe *find* through *xargs* and *grep*:

```
find ... | xargs grep '824'
```

This will list all the lines that contain "824", along with the filename and line number.  If you just want the filenames, then:

```
find ... | xargs grep -l '824'
```

*xargs* reads from *stdin*.  For each line read, it executes the command, passing the line as the last argument to the command.